# html and css formatting

Tags: html, css

Im new to web development and Im having some trouble getting my elements to format properly on the page. The website is being developed using html5/css3, and I am trying to get the "Welcome" justified left, the image box to the right, and then the My Account/Update text to the right of that. Please see the picture.

Everything I have tried so far has either resulted in everything justified to the left, or the elements appearing on separate lines.

Your help is appreciated.

Thanks
Chris

[image: welcome bar]

Comment: I would advise that you expand your question because you're not providing enough information for anyone to realistically help you. This usually leads to a protracted and frustrating round of requests in the comments for more information by other users who **really do want to help you**. For example, include in the question: code snippets/samples, the API you're using, stack traces, screen shots etc. When you've done this, flag to have your question re-opened. Please also take the time to [read this](http://tinyurl.com/so-hints). Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should help you get started:

http://jsfiddle.net/Eric/u5xvt/

---

#### HTML

```html
<div class="controls">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" />
    <span>My Account</span>
    <a>Update</a>
</div>
<p>Welcome,<br /> Chris</p>
```

#### CSS

```
.controls {
    float: right; /* push it to the right */
    width: 200px;
    background: #FFe0c0; /* Just so you can see what is going on */
    padding: 5px;
}
.controls img {
    float: left; /* push it to the left */
    margin-right: 5px;  
}
.controls span, .controls a{
    display: block;
    line-height: 50px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The CSS way of doing it is by using the `float` attribute.

```
<div class="Header">
    <div class="Welcome"></div>
    <div class="Image"></div>
    <div class="MyAccount"></div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
<div class="Body">
    ...
</div>
...
```

And the CSS for that:

```
.Welcome { float: left }
.Image { float: right }
.MyAccount { float: right }
.clear { clear: both }
```

The `clear:both` part's purpose is to make the Header expand around its contents - otherwise, Welcome, Image and MyAccount would actually appear on top of whatever's in Body.

Check out this great tutorial: http://css.maxdesign.com.au/floatutorial/

Answer (score 0):

You could try to Set float:left to get column like layout. 
In CSS3 maybe http://intensivstation.ch/files/css3/columns.html helps you too

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to wrap the elements on the right in a div that is floated right. Within that div, you'd want to display the image as a block element and float it left.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing code samples, I can only attempt to help. I would suggest wrapping all of your elements in something like a `header` tag, and then doing `text-align:left;`. Then, in theory, but floating your `img` to the right it should appear all on one line. Once code is posted I can test it further.